# Remove added backslashes from JSON string in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

So I'm trying to store some HTML code in the database and then retrieving it througth the API.

Initial HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.google.se/images/google_80w1ht.gif" alt="Google logo">
```

Then I store in the DB without any further hassle:

```
$data = $request->only(['content');

$comment = $this->repo->update($data, $id);
```

If I go to MySQL Workbench, this is the data stored:

```
<img src="https://www.google.se/images/google_80wht.gif" alt="Google logo">
```

However, the moment I retrieve it want want to output the HTML as a JSON parameter, it get's slahed all over the face.

This is the json:

```
{"title": "<img src=\"https://www.google.se/images/google_80w1ht.gif\" alt=\"Google logo\">"}
```

I have not applied any transformation nor during insert nor on retrieval.

How can I remove the added extra backslashes? ()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `json_decode(your_data)` this should work.

Comment: Yes of course :) Thanks.

I just went one step ahead and not realising that the client is always going to json_decode my JSON :P

Answer (score 2):

> I have not applied any transformation nor during insert nor on retrieval.

You converted it to JSON. That is a transformation.

> it get's slahed

The slashes are needed.

Without them this happens:

```
"<img src="h
^         ^^
|         ||
|         |Error
|         End of string
Start of string
```

The *data* doesn't contain the slashes, just the JSON representation of it. When you parse the JSON the escape sequences will be consumed and you will get your original string back.

Comment: Thank you, must be that I'm missing one cup of cofee this morning :)